# Adding Custom Control to XMLView

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to add an extension of sap.m.PlanningCalendar to my XML view. When it's added, the browser gives following error message:

***Cannot add direct child without default aggregation defined for control be.amistaAdminPlanning.controls.MyPlanningCalendar***

Is there anyone who can help me on my way or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

### XML VIEW

```
<mvc:View controllerName="be.amistaAdminPlanning.controller.AdminPlanning" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:unified="sap.ui.unified" displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic"
xmlns:controls="be.amistaAdminPlanning.controls">
<App>
    <pages>
        <semantic:FullscreenPage id="P1" title="{i18n>title}">
            <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
                <controls:MyPlanningCalendar id="PC1" rows="{path: '/people'}" appointmentsVisualization="Filled" groupAppointmentsMode="expanded"
                    appointmentsReducedHeight="true" appointmentSelect="onClickAssignment" showEmptyIntervalHeaders="false" viewChange="onStartDateChange"
                    startDateChange="onStartDateChange">
                    <toolbarContent>
                        <Title text="Assignments" titleStyle="H4"/>
                        <ToolbarSpacer/>
                        <Button id="addButton" icon="sap-icon://add" press="onAddAssignment" tooltip="Add"/>
                    </toolbarContent>
                    <views>
                        <PlanningCalendarView description="Day" intervalType="Hour" key="Hour" intervalsL="24" intervalsM="6" intervalsS="6"/>
                        <PlanningCalendarView description="Week" intervalType="Day" key="Day" intervalsL="7" intervalsM="7" intervalsS="7"/>
                        <PlanningCalendarView description="2 Weeks" intervalType="Week" key="Week" intervalsL="14" intervalsM="14" intervalsS="14"/>
                        <PlanningCalendarView description="Month" intervalType="One Month" key="One Month" intervalsL="31" intervalsM="1" intervalsS="1"/>
                        <PlanningCalendarView description="Year" intervalType="Month" key="Month" intervalsL="12" intervalsM="6" intervalsS="3"/>
                    </views>
                    <rows>
                        <PlanningCalendarRow id="PCR1" icon="{pic}" title="{name}" text="{role}" appointments="{path : 'appointments', templateShareable: 'true'}"
                            intervalHeaders="{path: 'headers', templateShareable: 'true'}">
                            <appointments>
                                <CalendarAppointment id="MCA1" startDate="{start}" endDate="{end}" icon="{pic}" title="{title}" text="{info}" type="{type}"
                                    tentative="{tentative}" hover="onAppointmentHover"/>
                            </appointments>
                            <intervalHeaders>
                                <unified:CalendarAppointment startDate="{start}" endDate="{end}" icon="{pic}" title="{title}" type="{type}"></unified:CalendarAppointment>
                            </intervalHeaders>
                        </PlanningCalendarRow>
                    </rows>
                </controls:MyPlanningCalendar>
            </VBox>
        </semantic:FullscreenPage>
    </pages>
</App>
```

### CUSTOM CONTROL

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/m/PlanningCalendar"], function(PlanningCalendar) {
    "use strict";
    return PlanningCalendar.extend("be.amistaAdminPlanning.controls.MyPlanningCalendar", {
        metadata: {
            properties: {},
            events: {},
            aggregations: {}
        },
        renderer: function(oRm, oControl) {
            sap.m.PlanningCalendarRenderer.render(oRm, oControl); //use supercass renderer routine
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prefix the aggregations with your controls XML namespace:

```
<controls:MyPlanningCalendar id="PC1" rows="{path: '/people'}">
  <controls:toolbarContent>
  </controls:toolbarContent>
  <controls:views>
  </controls:views>
  <controls:rows>
  </controls:rows>
</controls:MyPlanningCalendar>
```

This is not specific to your custom control. You will always have to do that when using a xml namespace.

BR Chris

Comment: Btw: Not specifying a renderer should give you the super renderer by default